# Binary array with loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have variable "n" which I use to give n bit count from the console, lets say n = 2, how do I make two separate arrays using loops that represents binary result: [00, 01, 10, 11] [00, 01, 10, 11] and then concatenate them to get result of:

```
          [00, 00] 
          [00, 01]
          [00, 10]
          [00, 11] then
          [01, 00] 
          [01, 01]
          [01, 10]
          [01, 11] etc.
```

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: " how do I make two separate arrays using loops that represents binary result "

Comment: If you want to store them as binary, use `0b` before your binary number. i.e `0b01`

Comment: It absolutely did. Now I only need to make the results from int to binary

Comment: What do you mean? binary is just a representation form of an int... Do you mean a string matching the binary representation?

Comment: The cycles are now [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)...] , I need to make them [(00,00), (00,01), (00, 10) ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this ->

```
from itertools import product
l1=  ['00', '01', '10', '11']
l2 = ['00', '01', '10', '11'] 

result = list(product(l1,l2))
```

**Output -**

```
[('00', '00'),
 ('00', '01'),
 ('00', '10'),
 ('00', '11'),
 ('01', '00'),
 ('01', '01'),
 ('01', '10'),
 ('01', '11'),
 ('10', '00'),
 ('10', '01'),
 ('10', '10'),
 ('10', '11'),
 ('11', '00'),
 ('11', '01'),
 ('11', '10'),
 ('11', '11')]
```

Via nested for loop ->

```
result = []
for val1 in l1:
    for val2 in l2:
        result.append((val1,val2))
```

Via list comprehension -

```
result = [(val1,val2) for val1 in l1 for val2 in l2]
```

If items in the initial list are of type int then use a dict to map them to respective binary values-

```
from itertools import product
l1=  [0, 1, 10, 11]
l2 = [0, 1, 10, 11] 
map_dict = {0 :'00',1 :'01', 10 : '10', 11 :'11'}
list(map(lambda x: (map_dict[x[0]],map_dict[x[1]]) ,list(product(l1,l2))))
```

Comment: Yes, something similar. I just need to use a nested loop to get the values (00,01,10,11) for each of the lists

Comment: added 2 more solutions @ERM

Comment: You don't need to declare two separate lists if they're both the same… `product(l1, l1)` does just fine.

Comment: @deceze yup point. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Or just `product(l1, repeat=2)`

Comment: I need two lists since the values can be different, its absolutely perfect. I just need to transform the result from int to binary

Comment: map_dict = {0 :'00',1 :'01', 10 : '10', 11 :'11'}
result = [(map_dict[val1],map_dict[val2]) for val1 in l1 for val2 in l2] @ERM Try this